# Parsing Json Output with PHP?

Tags: php, json

**Json Output:**

```
{
    trainno: "12934",
    trainname: "Karnavati Express",
    mon: 1,
    tue: 1,
    wed: 1,
    thu: 1,
    fri: 1,
    sat: 1,
    sun: 1,
    fromname: "Ahmedabad Jn",
    toname: "Mumbai Central"
    }
```

**Need to show output like below table:**

[image]

problem is how to separate this dynamic value of Run on like MON, Tue...

Thanks

Comment: So whats the issue over here

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: How to show this values on Runs On, this value changes with different train runs on like some train runs only sat etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chat this is the final answer.

```
$str = file_get_contents('put url here'); 
$json = json_decode($str, true); 

$day = ""; 
if($json['mon'] == 1){$day = $day."MON,";} 
if($json['tue'] == 1){$day = $day."tue,";} 
if($json['wed'] == 1){$day = $day."wed,";} 
if($json['thu'] == 1){$day = $day."thu,";} 
if($json['fri'] == 1){$day = $day."fri,";} 
if($json['sat'] == 1){$day = $day."sat,";} 
if($json['sun'] == 1){$day = $day."sun";} 


print_r($day) .'<br />';
```

## EDIT 2 Using array

```
$str = file_get_contents('put url here'); 
$json = json_decode($str, true);
$day2=array();
if($json['mon'] == 1){array_push($day2 , "MON";} 
if($json['tue'] == 1){array_push($day2 , "tue";} 
if($json['wed'] == 1){array_push($day2 , "wed";} 
if($json['thu'] == 1){array_push($day2 , "thu";} 
if($json['fri'] == 1){array_push($day2 , "fri";} 
if($json['sat'] == 1){array_push($day2 , "sat";} 
if($json['sun'] == 1){array_push($day2 , "sun";} 
print_r($day2);
```

Comment: `mon: 1, tue: 1,` into mon, tue

Comment: @OliviaNielsen I am sorry , i didn't get that comment, could you please explain

Comment: If we want to print this same value as I attached image here

Comment: @OliviaNielsen what other flags we get besides 1 ? 0 if do not runs on

Comment: can we change this Json Output to day array? Like `days: {mon, tue, wed...}`

Comment: can you post full json or url to get that json?

Comment: Note that you'll have trailing commas if trains don't run on Sunday. You should stuff the days into an array and do a final `join(', ', $days)` instead of directly appending to a string.